# Start a sentence with "even though"

Tags: grammar

I was told by my thesis advisor not to start a sentence with "even though". Does anyone agree? May I know why?

Comment: It strikes me as hyper-correction. Native speakers do it all the time.

Comment: Accepting an answer is difficult for this kind of a question, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there is no word *eventhough*; it needs to be *even though*.

Secondly, there is no sensible reason to avoid starting a sentence with *even though*, as long as the *even though* clause (which is a subordinate or dependent clause) is followed by a main or independent clause.

Thirdly, nothwithstanding 2 above, you should follow the instructions of your advisor.

Fourthly, you might want to ask this question directly of your advisor.

Comment: Thanks. Such an enlightening answer! However, I wonder whether the following two will have the same effect: **(1)** Dependent clause, followed by Independent clause **(2)** Independent clause followed by Dependent clause

Comment: @user52801: In general, whatever comes first in a sentence has the greatest prominence. So in the sentence _Because I was so tired, I went to bed straight after dinner_ the tiredness has prominence. Whereas in _I went to bed straight after dinner because I was so tired_ the going to bed has prominence. _Fronting_ is the term for moving an element to the beginning of the sentence for emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Even though is a conjunction and there's a grammar myth that sentences cannot be started with conjunctions.

While reality is conjunctions are of two types : 1) Co-ordinating conjunctions 2) Subordinating conjunctions.

And, but, or, yet, so are co-ordinating conjunctions that are used to combine sentences.

While, because, even though, although, until, unless are subordinating conjunctions which link to the main clause of sentence.

We use conjunctions at the beginning of a sentence : 1) I can solve this issue. **But** do you think boss will allow me to do so?

To conclude, I can say : We can start a sentence with Even though.

Please refer this link for details : http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/01/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction/

Examples of sentences where even though is used in the beginning of the sentence : http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_start_a_sentence_with_even_though

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer :) However, your answer spawned another question. Can this sentence "stand" on its own: "But do you think boss will allow me to do so?"? I think it is meaningless without the preceding sentence; thus it cannot be considered as a sentence. I am not sure though.

Comment: It’s a pretty smart and progressive budget. But do you think those changes go far enough? What do you think about this sentence

Comment: @user52801 Sentences only occur in contexts, so **all** sentences are meaningless outside their contexts.

Comment: @Sweet72 I think the second sentence does not have an existence on its own. I suggest that it should be "It’s a pretty smart and progressive budget, but do you think those changes go far enough?"

Comment: @user52801 : Conjuctions like but or and can be used at the start of sentence to show surprise.s

Comment: @user52801: “I brought you a turkey and cheese sandwich, here you go.” — “But I don't like cheese!” Nothing wrong with having an independent sentence start with a conjunction; it just has to be clear what it's conjuncting.

Answer (score 0):

Used to be an old-fashioned idea that you could not start sentences with conjunctions. As a child in the 1950s we were always told never to start a sentence with 'And'. But why not? Nowadays it is done all the time. However other changes in grammatical fashion I do not find so agreeable. Whilst split infinitives are used all over the place, especially by Americans I still find them clumsy and inelegant.

Comment: This answer would be better if you clarified that [_even though_ is a conjunction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even_though), and you removed the irrelevant grumbling about split infinitives.

Answer (score 0):

Samuel Johnson for English, Vaugelas for French, - and a lot of others - set up a number of unjustified rules.
Follow the common sense, and leave the so-called purists aside ; why on earth should they rule the words ?